# Вытаскивание data-атрибутов с определенной ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос:

Допустим, у нас есть несколько ссылок с data-атрибутами. Например:

```
<a href="#manual-modal" class="to_modal" data-desc="Descr #1"  data-name="Name #1"></a>
<a href="#manual-modal" class="to_modal" data-desc="Descr #2"  data-name="Name #2"></a>
<a href="#manual-modal" class="to_modal" data-desc="Descr #3"  data-name="Name #3"></a>
```

По клику мне нужно доставать данные с data-атрибутов, для того чтобы отобразить их в модальном окне. Но вот проблема: id у ссылок один и тот же. Как, тогда, достать данные именно с ссылки, по которой произошел клик?

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: `id у ссылок один и тот же` - *id* или всё же *class*. Если *id* - то лучше переделай, иначе проблем не оберешься

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработчике события `click` `this` указывает на *DOM* элемент, на котором произошло событие. Кроме того, в качестве параметра обработчику передается объект [*Event*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), у которого есть свойство `target`, также указывающее на *DOM* элемент.

```js
$('.to_modal').click(function(event) {

  console.log($(this).data())

  console.log($(event.target).data())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#manual-modal" class="to_modal" data-desc="Descr #1" data-name="Name #1">1</a>
<a href="#manual-modal" class="to_modal" data-desc="Descr #2" data-name="Name #2">2</a>
<a href="#manual-modal" class="to_modal" data-desc="Descr #3" data-name="Name #3">3</a>
```